# Spacemacs custom color

Tags: emacs, colors, color-scheme, spacemacs

I've recently switched to Spacemacs, and I'm trying to incorporate my own custom color theme. Normally, I do something like this.

```
(setq-default dotspacemacs-themes '(firebelly))  ;; additionally use with spacemacs

(use-package firebelly-theme
  :config (progn
        (let
        ;; This beautiful palette is shamelessly stolen from chris
        ;; kempson's base16: https://github.com/chriskempson/base16
        ;; I keep a local copy of the firebelly colour layout so I
        ;; can tweak it to my taste
        ((palette
          '("#ac4142" "#d28445" "#f4bf75" "#90a959"
            "#75b5aa" "#6a9fb5" "#aa759f" "#8f5536"))
         ;; Simple grayscale palette.
         (greys
          '("#222222" "#292929" "#444444" "#555555"
            "#666666" "#777777" "#888888" "#999999")))
          ;; Tiny functions to make getting from the palettes easier.
          (cl-flet
          ((color (n) (nth n palette))
           (grey (n) (nth n greys)))
        ;; Define some faces for our theme.
        (custom-theme-set-faces
         'firebelly
                 ;;;; Styling emacs.
         `(default
            ((t (:background ,(grey 0) :foreground ,(grey 7)))))
         `(cursor
           ((t (:background ,(grey 3)))))
         `(highlight
           ((t (:background ,(color 5) :foreground ,(grey 3)))))
         `(shadow
           ((t (:foreground ,(grey 6)))))
         `(isearch
           ((t (:background ,(grey 2) :foreground ,(color 6)))))
         `(query-replace
           ((t (:background ,(grey 2) :foreground ,(color 6)))))
         `(lazy-highlight
           ((t (:background ,(grey 1) :foreground ,(grey 3)))))
         `(minibuffer-prompt
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 1)))))
         `(trailing-whitespace
           ((t (:background ,(grey 1)))))
         `(nobreak-space
           ((t (:background ,(grey 1)))))
         `(escape-glyph
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 2)))))
         ;; Fringes are ugly.
         `(fringe
           ((t (:background ,(grey 0)))))
         ;; Highlight the border.
         `(vertical-border
           ((t (:foreground ,(grey 1)))))
         ;; Mode lines look the same but for the text.
         `(mode-line
           ((t (:background ,(grey 1) :foreground ,(grey 6) :box nil))))
         `(mode-line-inactive
           ((t (:background ,(grey 1) :foreground ,(grey 3) :box nil))))
         `(header-line
           ((t (:background ,(grey 1) :foreground ,(grey 3) :box nil))))
         `(mode-line-buffer-id
           ((t (:bold t))))
         `(mode-line-highlight
           ((t (:foreground ,(grey 7)))))
         ;; Regions are slightly lighter.
         `(region
           ((t (:background ,(grey 2)))))
         `(secondary-selection
           ((t (:background ,(grey 2)))))
    ;;;; Styling code.
         ;; Comments are lighter than their delimiters.
         `(font-lock-comment-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(grey 4)))))
         `(font-lock-comment-delimiter-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(grey 2)))))
         ;; Docstrings are slightly lighter.
         `(font-lock-doc-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(grey 4) :background ,(grey 0)))))
         `(font-lock-function-name-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 3)))))
         `(font-lock-variable-name-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(grey 2)))))
         `(font-lock-builtin-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 6)))))
         `(font-lock-constant-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 1)))))
         `(font-lock-type-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 4)))))
         `(font-lock-string-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 5) :background ,(grey 1)))))
         `(font-lock-keyword-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 6)))))
    ;;;; Styling extensions.
         ;; Erc faces.
         `(erc-notice-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(grey 2)))))
         `(erc-current-nick-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 3) :bold t))))
         `(erc-prompt-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 1) :background ,(grey 0)))))
         `(erc-input-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(grey 6)))))
         `(erc-my-nick-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 1)))))
         `(erc-error-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 0)))))
         `(erc-timestamp-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 3)))))
         ;; Rainbow delimiters are mostly in order.
         `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-1-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 7)))))
         `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-2-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 6)))))
         `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-3-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 5)))))
         `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-4-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(grey 3)))))
         `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-5-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 4)))))
         `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-6-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 3)))))
         `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-7-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 2)))))
         `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-8-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 1)))))
         `(rainbow-delimiters-depth-9-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 0)))))
         ;; shm faces
         `(shm-current-face
           ((t (:background ,(grey 1)))))
         `(shm-quarantine-face
           ((t (:foreground ,(color 0) :background ,(grey 1)))))
         ;; linum-relative faces
         `(linum-relative-current-face
           ((t (:background ,(grey 0) :foreground ,(color 1))))))))))
```

Spacemacs has a mechanism for [custom themes and colors](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/doc/DOCUMENTATION.org#color-themes). But that's not working, when called directly in my custom layer (see [here](http://spacemacs.org/doc/LAYERS.html#anatomy-of-a-layer) and [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30041/problems-creating-basic-spacemacs-layer)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, solved this one as well. I just took the [firebelly repo](https://github.com/startling/firebelly), made it a spacemacs layer. To do that, all I did was:

1. Clone the repo as a child dir to my **.spacemacs.d/layers** directory.
2. Made a soft link from **packages.el -> firebelly-theme.el** (A).
3. Added the new firebelly layer in the list of configuration layers in
   `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` (in **.spacemacs.d/init.el**) (B).

A)

```
firebelly/
├── firebelly-theme.el
├── packages.el -> firebelly-theme.el
├── readme.md
└── screenshot.png
```

B)

```
dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(
     ...
     firebelly)
```

Hope this helps others.